# Motion in helix-shaped wire

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, acceleration, centripetal-force

> A bead of mass $m$ is moving on a vertical axis helix shaped wire of uniform radius $R$ under force of gravity.

Can we apply centripetal force = $(mv^2)/R$ (at any instant when horizontal velocity is v)? I couldn't quite understand how we can or can't as the radius of curvature of its trajectory isn't $R$ (as this isn't a circular motion). But again the vertical and horizontal velocities are independent, so maybe we can. Any clarification would be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure. If you only consider the "polar part" of the motion, then for Newton's law in cylindrical coordinates we have

$$\mathbf F=m(\ddot r-r\dot\theta^2)\,\hat r+m(r\ddot\theta+2\dot r\dot\theta)\,\hat\theta+m\ddot z\,\hat z$$

Since the helix has a constant radius, the centripetal component of the force just becomes
$$F_c=-mr\dot\theta^2=-\frac{mv^2}{r}$$

where $v=r\dot\theta$ is the speed parallel to the x-y plane.

Of course, there is also a tangential component acting on the bead from the wire, and there is also the vertical force of gravity to consider (the other terms in the above equation) but that doesn't change how to look at the centripetal force here.

Remember, "centripetal force" is just the force component in some direction (in this case the center of the circle). It is just like saying "vertical force", "horizontal force" etc.

Also, note that to do this analysis you actually need to know what $\theta(t)$ is. Using Newtonian mechanics this seems like a backwards task, because we need to know the forces to determine $\theta(t)$. This is where Lagrangian mechanics would be useful, as you can determine $\theta(t)$ just from knowing about the constraints and energies of your system. Then from there you can apply Newtonian mechanics to actually determine the centripetal force acting on the bead.

Comment: I think there is an extra 'm' in the r hat component. Also, I have no idea of Lagrangian mechanics, so can't do what you suggested. And, Is the normal acceleration of the bead horizontal? I understand that tangential is in the direction of velocity, but what about normal acceleration?

Comment: @B.Anshuman Normal to what?

Comment: The net acceleration could be divided into 2 components, one along velocity and other perpendicular to it. The perpendicular component is what I am saying normal acceleration.

Comment: @FakeMod Please look at my answer again to see what I define $v$ to be

Comment: @B.Anshuman This is motion in 3D, so there isn't a unique direction normal to the velocity.

Comment: One more thing, how can we calculate the normal reaction applied by the wire on the bead? Can you just hint it, only from Newton's laws.

Comment: But your last paragraph says that to know the movement requires Lagrangian mechanics...

Comment: @B.Anshuman Yeah, if you explicitly want $\theta(t)$ then you will need Lagrangian mechanics (to my knowledge).

Comment: I think not, but maybe it is easier with Lagrangian mechanics. Anyway, just one last doubt on this question,if a body moves along any trajectory but is constrained to move in circular motion in a plane, we can always apply Fc=mv^2/r?

Comment: @B.Anshuman Yes, that is correct.